# how to fetch data from database in drupal7 in table form

Tags: drupal-7

```
    how to fetch data from database in drupal7:

    fields i have name:
                  subject:
                  email:
                  message:
     give me the code for drupal 7 i want it in table form.

my insert code is this:

function form_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    echo $name = $form_state['values']['textfield'];
    echo  $email = $form_state['values']['mail'];
    echo $subject = $form_state['values']['subject'];
    echo $message = $form_state['values']['message'];
     echo $ip=ip_address();
     echo $cb=$name;
      //echo $timestamp = REQUEST_TIME;
     echo $time=time();
     $nid=db_insert('form') // Table name no longer needs {}
  ->fields(array(
  'name' => $name,
  'email' => $email,
  'subject' => $subject,
  'message' => $message,
  'ip' => $ip,
  'created_by' => $cb,
  //'created_at' => $time,

))
->execute();
//print_r($nid);
    drupal_set_message(t('The form has been submitted.'));
    }
```

how can i fetch the data from database in drupal 7 in the form of table ,
give me the code .i m newbie in drupal 7 so its very difficult forme

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet to fetch all content from "form" table with table format and pager. Also you can add condition which I have added in comment if required.

```
<?php

// Set header
$header = array(
  array('data' => t('Name'), 'field' => 'name'),
  array('data' => t('Email'), 'field' => 'email'),
  array('data' => t('Subject'), 'field' => 'subject'),
  array('data' => t('Message'), 'field' => 'message'),
);

//query to fetch all content
$query = db_select('form', 'f');
$query->fields('f');

//$query->condition('f.name', $search_name, '=') //if needed

$table_sort = $query->extend('TableSort') // Table sort extender
  ->orderByHeader($header); // Order by headers

$pager = $table_sort->extend('PagerDefault')
  ->limit(20);  // Set page limit

$arr_result = $pager->execute();

$rows = array();
foreach($arr_result as $result) {
  $rows[] = array(
    $result->name, 
    $result->email,
    $result->subject,
    $result->message,
  );
}

// Set empty output
$output = '';

if (!empty($rows)) {

  $output = theme('table', array(
    'header' => $header,
    'rows' => $rows,
    /*'attributes' => array(
      'id' => 'sort-table' // add if want to add sorting
    ) */
  ));

  $output .= theme('pager');
}

else {
  $output .= t("No results found.");
}

return $output;

?>
```

Let me know if any query/confusion occurs for the same.